# WSO2 - Identity Server 6.1.0 - Cors filter

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

What is the equivalent in 6.1.0 (latest version of WSO2 identity server) of adding the below to <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
  
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

is it under the same file with same syntax? or should it be under deployment.toml as speicfied in the following documentation link: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/configure-cors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server versions prior to 5.11 enforced CORS using an open-source CORS filter. This filter was applied to the web.xml file of the internal Tomcat server in order to set the CORS configurations. A sample CORS configuration looked like above.

You can still set up the CORS configuration at the server level using the deployment.toml. As an example, you can set the same configuration mentioned for the web.xml as below.

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/configure-cors/#configuring-cors-during-deployment